# jQuery function parameters

Tags: jquery

Ok, so basically I just want to make a simple function that will change the CSS value of a div that has been clicked. The selected div ($(this)) will be passed to the divClicked function. I could just call the CSS jQuery function here but i want to perform the implementation in another function.

```
$('#container').children().click(function(){
    divClicked($(this));
});
```

but in the divClicked function when i go to run a jQuery function on the div variable it doesn't work... any idea what i'm doing wrong.

```
function divClicked(selectedDiv)
{
    $(selectedDiv).css('background', 'red');
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use `delegate` if I understand your question correctly. currently `this` does *not* refer to `#container`

Comment: zzzzBov: `this` refer to the div clicked... I think he got it right no?

Comment: can you post your code?  I can [get this to work](http://jsfiddle.net/8pgBv/) with the setup I have.

Comment: The first thing to determine is what's going wrong, which you can do with a debugger (Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE8 all have debuggers built in; you can get Firebug for Firefox, and VS.Net will debug in IE6 and IE7.) Because either 1) The event isn't getting hooked up, or 2) The `css` call isn't working. Should be easy enough to figure out which by walking through the code.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you doing the hookup? If it's in a `script` tag above the actual "container" `div` and you don't have it wrapped in some kind of `ready` callback or similar, that might be the problem. Or if you're adding children to the div afterward (since you're using `click`, which hooks up the handler only to the children there right then).

Because if the "container" `div` and its children already exist, your code works:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='Add a new child'>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  $("#container").append("<div>New child, clicking me <em>won't</em> work</div>");
});

$('#container').children().click(function(){
  divClicked($(this));
});

function divClicked(selectedDiv)
{
   // You don't want `$` here, but I've left it just to demonstrate
   // that your code should, largely, be working
   $(selectedDiv).css('background', 'red');
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ebide3/2)

...but note that elements added afterward *don't* work, because they weren't there when you hooked things up.

Fixing it will depend on what's wrong. It could just be wrapping your hook-up code in a [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler (as I have in that example) or moving it to code in a `script` tag at the bottom of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag (as the [YUI folks recommend](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)), or perhaps using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.  See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8pgBv/).  Is there something in your HTML we don't know?

But just as a note, you are already passing a jQuery object when you pass `$(this)`.  You then wrap it as a jQuery object again.  Instead use just `selectedDiv`.  Alternatively, pass `this` and use `$(selectedDiv)`.

Comment: And yet, it should work. jQuery's smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: @T. J. - hm...yes...see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pgBv/).  I have edited my response as noted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work anyway what "justkt" suggested..

Did you try "background-color" for your CSS style !?

Comment: I suppose there *could* be a browser out there that doesn't accept the shorthand property at that stage. I can't *find* one that doesn't (IE6, IE7, IE8, Chrome 9 [Win & Ubuntu], Firefox 3.6 [Win & Ubuntu], Opera 11 [Win & Ubuntu], and Safari 5 [Win] are all perfectly content with it), but it certainly would be reasonable to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery code for avoid the error. so its unavailable of live activities

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    $("#container").append("<div>New child, clicking me <em>won't</em> work</div>");
});

$(document).delegate('#container div', "click", function(){divClicked(this);});

var divClicked=function(selectedDiv) {
    $(selectedDiv).css('background', 'red');
};
```

});

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class="1">Child 1</div>
  <div class="2">Child 2</div>
  <div class="3">Child 3</div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='Add a new child'>
```